# Attack using the same scope names within differents api resources with OpenID Connect / OAuth2

Tags: attacks, oauth2, openid-connect

Assume that we have a `client X` and `client Y`. There's also api resources: `api-resource-1` and `api-resource-2`, and api scopes: `test.read` and `test.write`.

`Client X` is allowed to `test.read` within `api-resource-1` and `api-resource-2`. It's also allowed to `test.write` within `api-resource-1`, but `api-resource-2` also supports this scope (but client theoretically hasn't access to it).

But let's think. If `Client X` is allowed to `test.read` and `test.write` within `api-resource-1` and to `test.read` within `api-resource-2`, then received access token from token endpoint should look like this:

```
{
  "audience": "api-resource-1 api-resource-2",
  "scope": "test.read test.write"
}
```

As we can see, client got access to `test.write` within `api-resoruce-2` also, because while validating `api-resource-2` isnt able to recognize that this is intended for another api resource.

So by using multiple audiences we are vulnerable to such an attack.

So what we should do to protect our api resources against this attack? Should token endpoint generate another access token for any audience?

How to solve this problem? Or maybe I just misunderstand how scopes work? Currently I understand it like this: some api resource register it's scopes at authorization server, and then api resource can also set which clients should have access to his scopes. But take into consideration that when client send request with scopes e.g. to authorization endpoint then audience (api resource) isn't specified, so we have to use multiple audiences if scopes have the same names.

Comment: Why api-resource-2 is added into the audience? Do api-resource-1 & api-resource-2 have any common role in them?

Comment: No, they don't have. But how can I handle token response if client requested scopes for different api resources?

Comment: I expressed myself wrong in comment. Api-resource-2 is added into the audience because it also uses test.write scope. Problem is that client is allowed to test.write in api-resource-1, not in api-resource-2.

Comment: It's better to create 2 custom scopes with read & write and with read only. Then have client X to request either of one.

Comment: What if two resources request the same name? May use the prefix in scope name that includes e.g. resource name? Also, if the client requests scopes for different resources, what to do? Several access tokens or many audiences (what is risky without certificate-bound access tokens)

Comment: The problem that I'm seeing here is that api-resource-2 is being automatically added as the audience for the token. This shouldn't be that way unless that resource is globally accessible by default for all the clients.

Comment: So how should I generate access token if client requested scopes which give access to different api resources?